# Arabic font issue in the Android WebView

Tags: android, html, css, fonts, webview

I am trying to load a HTML file into android webview. I have `fonts` and `html` folder inside the assests. In the fonts folder I have `Arabic Regular.otf` and `Arabic Bold.otf`. On loading the page into webview i can't see the difference between bold and regular fonts. I have searched in SO, and then changed the font from `otf` to `svg` format. It works fine for me in Jelly Bean, but not exactly in HoneyComb. Please Help.

My styles in HTML file.

```
.c0{direction:rtl}


p span.medium { font-family:"AdobeArabic-Bold", sans-serif; }
p span { font-family:"AdobeArabic-Regular", sans-serif; }


@font-face {
font-family: 'AdobeArabic-Regular';
src: url('file:///android_asset/fonts/AdobeArabic-Regular.svg');    
}

@font-face {
font-family: 'AdobeArabic-Bold';
src: url('file:///android_asset/fonts/AdobeArabic-Bold.svg');    
}
```

And my Activity Code;

```
WebView wv=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/html/policy.html");
```

And my HTML code is

```
<p class="c0"><span class="medium">المعلومات التي تقدمها.</span></p>
<p class="c0"><span>لكي تتمكن من تصفح هذا الموقع، يجب عليك إدخال بعض المعلومات الشخصية المعرفة (مثل الإسم والبريد الإلكتروني وتاريخ الميلاد). بهدف أن تستفيد من بعض المزايا المميزة. سوف يتم إعلامك أية معلومات مطلوبة منك وأيها اختياري ولأي هدف سنستخدمها.</span></p>
```

Comment: Have you tried `ttf` font format?

Comment: @gnclmorais. No. Not Yet, Do u think it will resolve

Comment: Don't exactly know, but it is a more standard format...
Also, declare the `font-faces` before using them, since this is CSS.

Comment: @gnclmorais. I have tried ttf format. Its not showing any difference between Regular and Bold in JellyBean.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this, setting them as the same family, but different weights:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "AdobeArabic";
    src: url('file:///android_asset/fonts/AdobeArabic-Regular.svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "AdobeArabic";
    src: url('file:///android_asset/fonts/AdobeArabic-Bold.svg');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

And then:

```
p span {
    font-family: "AdobeArabic-Regular", sans-serif;
}
p span.medium {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: I have tried the way as u said, but its not showing the difference.

Comment: Hm, this is very weird, indeed... Can you provide some HTML example of what you are trying to style, please?

Comment: Is that a good way to use two html files with different fonts and styles and load accordingly by checking the android version programatically at run time?

Comment: You could try that... I don't know why it is not working. It might be a Webkit bug.